# React-Redux: Forms in component or container?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have some difficulties understanding when to use components and when to user containers. I know that only containers are supposed to be connected to the store and all (presentational) components should get all necessary inputs as props.

If I want to write, let's say, a login page, I would create a `LoginPage.js` that renders a `UserForm.js`. Now I don't quite understand how to proceed from here. Should I connect UserForm to the store or LoginPage or would it be even better to write a `LoginContainer.js` that renders `LoginPage.js` and is connected to the store?

In the last case how do I dispatch an (async, using redux-thunk,) action when UserForm is submitted. this somehow has to be done from LoginPage but LoginPage does not know about any submits, does it?

I hope this question is not too vague or unclear.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connect your `LoginPage.js` to redux store and render `LoginForm.js` inside it. Pass all necessary data as props (may pass functions as well)

for ex- 
your `LoginPage.js` will be something like this (i'm not writing full code here)

```
onLogin(loginData) {
  // do what you wanna do on login and call routeActions to move another 
  page after successfull login 
}
render() {
 return(
   <LoginForm login={this.props.login} onLogin={this.onLogin} />
 );
}
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   login: state.login, // put your redux state here
 });
 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginPage);
```

don't forget to declare props...

and your `LoginForm.js` should be something like this

```
render() {
  return (
     //some html stuff here(login form)
     // on submit call that method from props 
     // this.props.onLogin(pass login data here)
  );
}
```

i hope this will help you somehow.
if you have any query post here...

Comment: So I would have to dispatch some LOGIN_REQUEST action in onLogin() then?

Comment: Thanks! Could you briefly comment on why this is would be the recommended way? Why is connecting the LoginForm directly or creating an additional container for LoginPage not a good idea?

Comment: Basically your components are supposed to be dumb... That aren't aware of redux stores/states... They are only presentational components... And again you can have containers that is more appropriate way to do it... Your pages will contain components that are connected to routes... Then these will render containers... This is the way I personally like to do... In the end it depends on you how you wanna structure your project.....